# Integration related question

Tags: calculus, integration

how does one integrate $ (x^3-1) /( 4x^3-x)  dx$ ?

I tried dividing polynomials but it didnt help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{x^3-1}{4x^3-x} \equiv -\frac{7}{8}\left(\frac{1}{2x-1}\right)-\frac{9}{8}\left(\frac{1}{2x+1}\right)+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{4},$$ which you should be able to integrate.

---

I got this result by factorising the numerator and the denominator as $\frac{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}{x(2x-1)(2x+1)}$ and then used partial fractions.

Comment: Awesome, thanks bro...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
 For this type of integrals, you perform a [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). For instance with your particular integral you get:
$$\dfrac{x^3-1}{4x^3-x}=-\dfrac7{8(2x-1)}-\dfrac9{8(2x+1)}+\dfrac1x+\dfrac14.$$
The rest is straightforward.